# ContainerView causes breaking constraint of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have three `UIViewController()` for my app. First is `EmptyVC` and second is my view that shows data in `UITableView`. Third one is container view to separate these `UIViewController()s` each other. All of them is created using `storyboard` Whenever there isn't data available container shows `EmptyVC` and when data comes it shows my `UITableView()`. Following is my `ContainerVC`

```
class FidelityContainerVC: UIViewController {
    private var presentingVC: UIViewController?
    private var state: State?
    private let fidelityVC = FidelityVC()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        transition(to: .render(fidelityVC))
        transition(to: .loading)
    }

    func transition(to newState: State) {
        presentingVC?.remove()
        let vc = viewController(for: newState)
        add(vc)
        presentingVC = vc
        state = newState
    }
}

extension FidelityContainerVC {
    enum State {
        case loading
        case render(UIViewController)
    }
}

private extension FidelityContainerVC {
    func viewController(for state: State) -> UIViewController {
        switch state {
        case .loading:
            return EmptyVC()
        case .render(let viewController):
            return viewController
        }
    }
}
```

`Add` and `remove` are extension methods for `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        addChild(child)
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func remove() {
        guard parent != nil else {
            return
        }
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

My problem is when I add my `EmptyVC` to the `ContainerVC` constraints are broken and views are irrelevant. I do not understand what causes that. What could be the reason and how can I fix that?

Comment: If you programmatically add view to superview, you must programmatically add constraints for it right after that.

Comment: Isn't there any way to achieve without constraint? @Asperi

Comment: No. It was always, in pre-autolayout era we did the same - set frame + autoresizing mask. How would layout system know where to place newly added view.